# Strip part of URI path with TCL

Tags: tcl, f5

I'm fairly new with programming and TCL. I'm working on F5 iRules which utilize tcl.

Essentially what I need to do is strip out the first portion (/Version_13.0.001/) of my URI path below:
`/Version_13.0.001/hs/user/123`

Making the end result URI to:
`/hs/user/123`

Below is the basic logic I have, how would I incorporate this into my below irule?

```
  if { ([HTTP::path] contains "Version_13") } {
    pool version_13_pool }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`split`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/split.htm) or [`file split`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm) to break apart the path, remove the dirname at index 1, and then [`join`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/join.htm) or `file join`.

However, it seems more straightforward to do a regular expression search and replace:

```
set path "/Version_13.0.001/hs/user/123"
set newpath [regsub {^/Version_13[^/]*} $path ""]
puts $newpath     ; # => /hs/user/123
```

Here, we're finding, at the beginning of the string, "/Version_13" followed by non-slash characters, and replacing that with an empty string.

Or perhaps use the [`string`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm) command to find the index of 2nd slash, and take the substring starting from there:

```
set newpath [string range $path [string first / $path 1] end]
```